# Convert list into string in bash

Tags: shell, shell-script

I want to convert list into string with unix command. X is a variable and store in new variable Y.

X =  ['8922','9292','3220'] to
'8922,9292,3220'

How can I do this. Please suggest.

Comment: (1) What is the rule for changing `92998192` to `9292`? (2) Can you clarify your question, in general?  For example, do you have the “list” in a variable or a file?  Will every element of the list be in quotes? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable `X` that contains `['8922','9292','3220']`,
you can get `Y` equal to `'8922,9292,3220'`
(including the quotes as part of the string) by doing

```
Y=$(echo "$X" | sed "s/\[//; s/]//; s/','/,/g")
```

This removes the `[` (at the beginning) and the `]` (at the end). 
Then it removes the interior quotes by targeting the word boundaries
(wherever there is a `,`)
and changing (for example) `…quick','brown…` to `…quick,brown…`.

There are many many variations on this. 
For example, if some of the list elements might not be quoted
(e.g., `['8922',42,'3220']`), try

```
Y =\'$(echo "$X" | sed "s/\[//; s/]//; s/'//g")\'
```

This removes *all* quotes from `$X`,
and then re-applies quotes at the beginning and end.

Comment: If this doesn’t work for you, please [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1065839/edit) your question to describe what you did and what happened. You don’t have to reveal your *actual* data, but please create an example that demonstrates the problem. Then post a comment here to alert me.